# Firestore Connection Dropped Error in React Unit Test

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore as my backend for my React app. I'm implementing unit testing, but it throws me an error as such:

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.14.0): Connection GRPC stream error. Code: 14 Message: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connection dropped
```

After that, it logs me another error:

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.14.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=unavailable]: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connection dropped
    This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend
```

My guess is that I'm unable to call to the database when unit testing.

Is there a way I can work around this error? Or do I have to make a mock for it? If yes, is there a reference I can refer to regarding this?

Comment: You can use the Firebase emulator to use the database locally, but I still prefer mocking to make the tests more independent.

Comment: @GabrielNexT Do you have reference I can refer to regarding mocking Firestore?

Comment: I don't because it varies depending on your test library, but I know there are some packages for jest.